# Code for determining beats per min when timing a wooden clock

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm new to Arduino and coding but I build wooden clocks.  The biggest problem is timing the clock to the correct beats per min when adjusting pendulum length.  I'm thinking Arduino and an IR sensor?? to detect when the pendulum breaks the beam, then displaying the beats per min real time would be possible.  If not real time then just beats in a variable time period, ie 1 min or 2 or 5 or 10 min.  I've looked for this type of code and circuit but haven't been able to find one.  Any help would sincerely be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of accuracy level do you require? Like a few ppm?

Comment: No, needs to be down to tenth or hundreth of a min.  What I currently do is use a stopwatch to measure 60 beats (for example) and see what time period that is.  Obviously 60 beats in 1 min would be accurate (however some clocks have 90 beats per min)  If that isn't possible then counting the beats in a 2 or 5 min or 10 min cycle would start narrowing things down.

Comment: Better yet: made the Arduino control a weight in the pendulum to adjust (higher/lower) his center of mass and automatically keep it to 60 bps. Arduino, battery and motor can be hidden inside the pendulum bob. That's will be cool: the most precise and stable pendulum wooden clock of the world.

Answer (score 1):

If the accuracy you require is about 1%, that should be doable with any
Arduino. Much higher accuracies would be hard to achieve because most
Arduinos are clocked off a ceramic resonator, and these have a frequency
tolerance of about 0.5%.

Given that your signal is very slow, the simplest approach may be to
poll the pin connected to the sensor and record the time (using
`micros()`) of the low → high transition. Then you can compute the
beat frequency as the inverse of the time between consecutive
transitions.

There is, however, the possibility that the sensor is not exactly in
the middle of the swing. Then, for better accuracy, I would measure the
time taken by *two* beats, i.e. a full swing. This way the pssible
asymmetry will not affect the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have the Arduino send a message to the PC when a 'tick' occurs. Then have the PC do the calculations over a larger number of ticks. You can even have the PC measure it's drift using NTP (PC clocks also aren't extremely accurate, but better that the crystal on the Arduino).

The procedure that I used, I found at https://www.logre.eu/wiki/Horloge_analogique_24h/en#Quartz_calibration I ran it for a few hours. Which might also be useful in your case to see if the swing is consistent.

I used this to calibrate my Arduino clock to within a few seconds per year,

Comment: Thanks so much for the info and direction to head.  Now I'll figure out if I understood all this wisdom, like I said, new to coding.  Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: At that point you might as well just use the PC to record the ticking sound and process it in software.  Or if you can't work in a quiet environment, couple the sensor the PC audio input with a capacitor.